# Previous CUDA kernel calls have an impact to the another kernel call

Tags: c++, c, cuda

While following the reference related to the parallel reduction algorithms (https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf), I met quite a strange situation.

I made respective 'reduce0', 'reduce1', ..., 'reduce6' exactly the same as what has described on the reference, and if I run them individually they work as a charm.

However, if I run, for example, 'reduce1' followed by 'reduce0', 'reduce1' generates a strange value.

```
__global__ void reduce0(int *g_idata, int *g_odata) {    
  extern __shared__ int sdata[];                         
                                                         
  unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;                        
  unsigned int i   = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
                                                         
  sdata[tid] = g_idata[i];                               
  __syncthreads();                                       
                                                         
  //reduction in shared memory                           
  for(unsigned int s=1; s<blockDim.x; s *= 2 ) {         
    if (tid % (2*s) == 0 ) {                             
      sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + s];                      
    }                                                    
    __syncthreads();                                     
  }                                                      
                                                         
  // write result for this bloc to global memory         
  if (tid == 0) g_odata[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];

  // Try to initialize the shared memory
  //sdata[tid] = 0;
  //__syncthreads();
}
```

```
__global__ void reduce1(int *g_idata, int *g_odata) {    
  extern __shared__ int sdata[];                         
                                                         
  unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;                        
  unsigned int i   = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
                                                         
  sdata[tid] = g_idata[i];                               
  __syncthreads();                                       
                                                         
  //reduction in shared memory                           
  for(unsigned int s=1; s<blockDim.x; s *= 2 ) {         
    int index = 2*s*tid;                                 
                                                         
    if (index < blockDim.x) {                            
      sdata[index] += sdata[index+s];                    
    }                                                    
                                                         
    __syncthreads();                                     
  }                                                      
                                                         
  // write result for this bloc to global memory         
  if (tid == 0) g_odata[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];          
}
```

```
int main() {
  int *arr;
  int *arr_block;
  int *dev_arr, *dev_arr_block;
  int n_block, n_threads;
  int n_data = 100;

  // allocation
  arr = (int *)malloc(n_data*sizeof(int));
  cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_arr, n_data*sizeof(int));
  // 0~99 filled
  for (int i = 0; i<n_data; i++) {
    arr[i] = i;
  }
  cudaMemcpy(dev_arr, arr, n_data*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  n_threads = 512;
  n_block   = n_data/n_threads+1;
  arr_block = (int *)malloc(n_block*sizeof(int));
  cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_arr_block, n_block*sizeof(int));

  // reduce0
  reduce0<<<n_block, n_threads, n_threads*sizeof(int)>>>(dev_arr, dev_arr_block);
  cudaMemcpy(arr_block, dev_arr_block, n_block*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  int sum0 = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i<n_block; i++) {
    sum0 += arr_block[i];
  }

  // reduce1
  reduce1<<<n_block, n_threads, n_threads*sizeof(int)>>>(dev_arr, dev_arr_block);
  cudaMemcpy(arr_block, dev_arr_block, n_block*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  int sum1 = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i<n_block; i++) {
    sum1 += arr_block[i];
  }

  printf("sum0/1 = \n 0 %d \n 1 %d \n", sum0, sum1);

  cudaFree(dev_arr);
  cudaFree(dev_arr_block);
  free(arr_block);

  return 0;
}
```

The above `main` calculates the sum of 0~99 integers, and the right value is 4950, which is easily calculable by hand.

```
sum0/1 = 
 0 4950 
 1 9900
```

However, the 'reduce1' gives a wrong value. However, if I remove the 'reduce0' call, then 'reduce1' also gives the desired result.

I really cannot get what is the cause, since all kernel calls seem well separated in their input and output.

The main candidate (and I would say, the only one possible candidate) is the `extern __shared__`, but the situation does not change if I put some 'initializing' lines - The commented in the 'reduce0' function. (But in fact, it would be also strange if the 'initializing the shared memory' had worked because the shared memory should have been cleared with every end of the kernel calls.)

Could anyone give some comment here?

Comment: you have 100 items but 512 threads which execute `sdata[tid] = g_idata[i];` This causes out of bounds access, and you probably access the result of the previous kernel that way.

Comment: @AbatorAbetor, indeed!! After restricting the access by `tid` via `if (i<n_data)`, where n_data = 100 in this case, the problem was resolved. If you are willing to write an answer in a short way, I will happily accept yours

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your program is making out-of-bounds memory accesses. For future reference, you can use [compute-sanitizer](https://docs.nvidia.com/compute-sanitizer/) (provided by NVIDIA in the CUDA toolkit) to detect such issues:

```
$ nvcc -lineinfo -o test test.cu
$ compute-sanitizer --print-limit 1 --show-backtrace device ./test
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
========= Invalid __global__ read of size 4 bytes
=========     at 0x60 in /tmp/tmp.IA2kr35y0x/test.cu:9:reduce0(int *, int *)
=========     by thread (160,0,0) in block (0,0,0)
=========     Address 0x7f027f200280 is out of bounds
=========     and is 125 bytes after the nearest allocation at 0x7f027f200200 of size 4 bytes
=========
sum0/1 =
 0 134246924
 1 134246924
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 359 errors
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 358 errors were not printed. Use --print-limit option to adjust the number of printed errors
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know such a great debugging tool, I didn't aware of it